# Can't close Python application

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, wxpython

I have a server application which receives messages from other applications on the same network via sockets and constantly runs waiting for messages. It is actually just a trigger, which this seems to be working fine.

But I can't close the application. When I hit close, the GUI freezes and I can't find a solution. Here is a relevant portion of the server code:

```
class blah blah...

    def handler(self, clientsocket, clientaddr):
        clientsocket.close()
        threading.Thread(target=self.SendFolder).start()

    def listen(self):
        host = ''
        port = 55567
        buf = 1024
        addr = (host, port)
        self.serversocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.serversocket.bind(addr)
        self.serversocket.listen(2)
        while 1:
            print "Server is listening for connections\n"     
            clientsocket, clientaddr = self.serversocket.accept()
            threading.Thread(target=self.handler, args=(clientsocket, clientaddr)).start()
        self.serversocket.close()

    def OnClose(self, e):
        wx.CallAfter(CloseApp())


class CloseApp(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(e):
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: You are starting threads but not stopping them before exit!

Comment: when you need to exist you will have to close all threads you started...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about cleaning up the threads at program exit, consider flagging them as "daemon" threads.

It is good practice to clean up your threads (and sockets) - without knowing how your app hangs together that could perhaps go in OnClose().  For example, is it ok to terminate self.SendFolder() at any point or does it need to complete its current operation?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using `self.listenThread.daemon= True` when starting the looping thread.
So now when I use my 'Close' button the app exists correctly, no freeze.
If I click the 'X' in the top right of the application (Windows) the application closes, but the thread does not exit correctly, anyway I can get around that?

Comment: so maybe you should consider upvoting my answer.